# position a div on input element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to position a div on input element. for eg.

https://www.tumblr.com/login

If you look at password input element,there is a '?' on right side.

What is the RIGHT soln to do it?

I was trying to position it using absolute against body which does not work well.

I wanted to position "?" relative to input element as its containing div but I can not make input element a parent div for "?" for some reason.

Please help.

Code:

```
  div.login
    form#login-form(autocomplete="on", method='post', action='/login')
      div.form-row
        label(for="login_email")
        input#login_email(type="email" , data-required="required", placeholder="Email", name="user[email]")
      div.form-row
        label(for="login_password")
        input#login_password(type="password" , data-required="required", placeholder="Password", name="user[password]")
          div.forgot(style='float:right;border:1px solid red;') forgot
      input.login-btn.btn-account(type='submit', value='Log in')
```

Comment: thanks a lot guys. I got it working. I did an upvote and accepted 1 answer as thats all the power I got from SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, the input element, and the question market element, are parented in the div element with class `form_row`:

```
    <div class="form_row form_row_password">
         <label for="signup_password">Password</label>
         <input type="password" name="user[password]" placeholder="Password" id="signup_password" data-required="required">
         <a href="/forgot_password" class="forgot_password_link" target="_new">Password help<b class="question_mark">?</b></a>
    </div>
```

So, the parent div, with class `form_row` is `position:relative;`, then the input element AND `<a>` element are within that.  The `<a>` element is the only one with `position:absolute` and that becomes relative to its parent, the container div and not the input element.

Answer (score 2):

I would make the `div.form-row` `position:relative` and the `div.forgot` `position:absolute;right:10px;top:8px;`

That will absolute position the forgot or "?" itself relative to the input field's parent container. You will need to adjust it further but this should get you headed in the right direction.